# USRP_UHD doesn't provide data

Tags: redhawksdr, usrp

After allocation of USRP, by inserting the appropriate code in the waveform xml file, I connect dataShort_out of USRP to DataConverter input port, such as DataShort but monitoring this port we can find nothing althought the allocation seems work fine. from monitor port panel appears: Call/s = about 30; MB/s = 0; Element/s = 0; Average queue dept = 2% Time=0;
Appended find the sad.xml of my waveform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE softwareassembly PUBLIC "-//JTRS//DTD SCA V2.2.2 SAD//EN" "softwareassembly.dtd">
<softwareassembly id="DCE:c679e5d8-3193-4a96-9cdb-9f28135f63c9" name="usrp_test_waveform">
  <componentfiles>
    <componentfile id="DataConverter_6b5c2ee8-0e91-4ed0-af3b-2677f27c21ed" type="SPD">
      <localfile name="/components/DataConverter/DataConverter.spd.xml"/>
    </componentfile>
    <componentfile id="TuneFilterDecimate_4552fe55-6bd9-4fd2-b0ce-ba184199263e" type="SPD">
      <localfile name="/components/TuneFilterDecimate/TuneFilterDecimate.spd.xml"/>
    </componentfile>
    <componentfile id="AmFmPmBasebandDemod_16af112f-1335-424c-a4d6-972c63f1bd43" type="SPD">
      <localfile name="/components/AmFmPmBasebandDemod/AmFmPmBasebandDemod.spd.xml"/>
    </componentfile>
    <componentfile id="multiply_const_ff_abfee3c0-41de-42a3-b3ae-b2ba1a2fca50" type="SPD">
      <localfile name="/components/gnuhawk/gr/multiply_const_ff/current/multiply_const_ff.spd.xml"/>
    </componentfile>
    <componentfile id="AudioSink_2e8025e4-743f-4387-b129-bb15a4e1992b" type="SPD">
      <localfile name="/components/AudioSink/AudioSink.spd.xml"/>
    </componentfile>
  </componentfiles>
  <partitioning>
    <componentplacement>
      <componentfileref refid="DataConverter_6b5c2ee8-0e91-4ed0-af3b-2677f27c21ed"/>
      <componentinstantiation id="DataConverter_1" startorder="4">
        <usagename>DataConverter_1</usagename>
        <findcomponent>
          <namingservice name="DataConverter_1"/>
        </findcomponent>
      </componentinstantiation>
    </componentplacement>
    <componentplacement>
      <componentfileref refid="TuneFilterDecimate_4552fe55-6bd9-4fd2-b0ce-ba184199263e"/>
      <componentinstantiation id="TuneFilterDecimate_1" startorder="5">
        <usagename>TuneFilterDecimate_1</usagename>
        <findcomponent>
          <namingservice name="TuneFilterDecimate_1"/>
        </findcomponent>
      </componentinstantiation>
    </componentplacement>
    <componentplacement>
      <componentfileref refid="AmFmPmBasebandDemod_16af112f-1335-424c-a4d6-972c63f1bd43"/>
      <componentinstantiation id="AmFmPmBasebandDemod_1" startorder="1">
        <usagename>AmFmPmBasebandDemod_1</usagename>
        <findcomponent>
          <namingservice name="AmFmPmBasebandDemod_1"/>
        </findcomponent>
      </componentinstantiation>
    </componentplacement>
    <componentplacement>
      <componentfileref refid="TuneFilterDecimate_4552fe55-6bd9-4fd2-b0ce-ba184199263e"/>
      <componentinstantiation id="TuneFilterDecimate_2" startorder="2">
        <usagename>TuneFilterDecimate_2</usagename>
        <findcomponent>
          <namingservice name="TuneFilterDecimate_2"/>
        </findcomponent>
      </componentinstantiation>
    </componentplacement>
    <componentplacement>
      <componentfileref refid="multiply_const_ff_abfee3c0-41de-42a3-b3ae-b2ba1a2fca50"/>
      <componentinstantiation id="multiply_const_ff_1" startorder="3">
        <usagename>multiply_const_ff_1</usagename>
        <findcomponent>
          <namingservice name="multiply_const_ff_1"/>
        </findcomponent>
      </componentinstantiation>
    </componentplacement>
    <componentplacement>
      <componentfileref refid="DataConverter_6b5c2ee8-0e91-4ed0-af3b-2677f27c21ed"/>
      <componentinstantiation id="DataConverter_2" startorder="0">
        <usagename>DataConverter_2</usagename>
        <findcomponent>
          <namingservice name="DataConverter_2"/>
        </findcomponent>
      </componentinstantiation>
    </componentplacement>
    <componentplacement>
      <componentfileref refid="AudioSink_2e8025e4-743f-4387-b129-bb15a4e1992b"/>
      <componentinstantiation id="AudioSink_1" startorder="6">
        <usagename>AudioSink_1</usagename>
        <findcomponent>
          <namingservice name="AudioSink_1"/>
        </findcomponent>
      </componentinstantiation>
    </componentplacement>
  </partitioning>
  <assemblycontroller>
    <componentinstantiationref refid="DataConverter_2"/>
  </assemblycontroller>
  <connections>
    <connectinterface id="usrpAllocation">
      <usesport>
        <usesidentifier>dataShort_out</usesidentifier>
        <deviceusedbyapplication usesrefid="DCE:18964b3d-392e-4b98-a90d-0569b5d46ffe"/>
      </usesport>
      <providesport>
        <providesidentifier>dataShort</providesidentifier>
        <componentinstantiationref refid="DataConverter_2"/>
      </providesport>
    </connectinterface>
    <connectinterface id="connection_1">
      <usesport>
        <usesidentifier>dataFloat_Out</usesidentifier>
        <componentinstantiationref refid="TuneFilterDecimate_1"/>
      </usesport>
      <providesport>
        <providesidentifier>dataFloat_In</providesidentifier>
        <componentinstantiationref refid="AmFmPmBasebandDemod_1"/>
      </providesport>
    </connectinterface>
    <connectinterface id="connection_2">
      <usesport>
        <usesidentifier>fm_dataFloat_out</usesidentifier>
        <componentinstantiationref refid="AmFmPmBasebandDemod_1"/>
      </usesport>
      <providesport>
        <providesidentifier>dataFloat_In</providesidentifier>
        <componentinstantiationref refid="TuneFilterDecimate_2"/>
      </providesport>
    </connectinterface>
    <connectinterface id="connection_3">
      <usesport>
        <usesidentifier>float_out</usesidentifier>
        <componentinstantiationref refid="multiply_const_ff_1"/>
      </usesport>
      <providesport>
        <providesidentifier>dataFloat</providesidentifier>
        <componentinstantiationref refid="DataConverter_1"/>
      </providesport>
    </connectinterface>
    <connectinterface id="connection_4">
      <usesport>
        <usesidentifier>dataFloat_Out</usesidentifier>
        <componentinstantiationref refid="TuneFilterDecimate_2"/>
      </usesport>
      <providesport>
        <providesidentifier>float_in</providesidentifier>
        <componentinstantiationref refid="multiply_const_ff_1"/>
      </providesport>
    </connectinterface>
    <connectinterface id="connection_5">
      <usesport>
        <usesidentifier>dataFloat_out</usesidentifier>
        <componentinstantiationref refid="DataConverter_2"/>
      </usesport>
      <providesport>
        <providesidentifier>dataFloat_In</providesidentifier>
        <componentinstantiationref refid="TuneFilterDecimate_1"/>
      </providesport>
    </connectinterface>
    <connectinterface id="connection_6">
      <usesport>
        <usesidentifier>dataShort_out</usesidentifier>
        <componentinstantiationref refid="DataConverter_1"/>
      </usesport>
      <providesport>
        <providesidentifier>audio_in</providesidentifier>
        <componentinstantiationref refid="AudioSink_1"/>
      </providesport>
    </connectinterface>
  </connections>
  <usesdevicedependencies>
        <usesdevice id="DCE:18964b3d-392e-4b98-a90d-0569b5d46ffe" type="usesUSRP">
            <propertyref refid="DCE:cdc5ee18-7ceb-4ae6-bf4c-31f983179b4d" value="FRONTEND"/>
            <propertyref refid="DCE:0f99b2e4-9903-4631-9846-ff349d18ecfb" value="USRP"/>
            <structref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation">
                <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::tuner_type" value="RX_DIGITIZER"/>
                <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::allocation_id" value="usrpAllocation"/>
                <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::center_frequency" value="102500000"/>
                <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::bandwidth" value="320000"/>
                <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::sample_rate" value="250000"/>
                <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::group_id" value=""/>
                <simpleref refid="FRONTEND::tuner_allocation::rf_flow_id" value=""/>
            </structref>
        </usesdevice>
    </usesdevicedependencies>
</softwareassembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue in REDHAWK 1.9 without any luck. I simplified your waveform by removing all connections and components from the waveform except the first DataConverter component. I also kept the USRP_UHD allocation and the connection between the USRP_UHD and the DataConverter. This focuses on the USRP_UHD device without introducing potential issues from the components that were removed. In my testing, data flows from the USRP_UHD device through the DataConverter as expected. Monitoring the USRP_UHD's `dataShort_out` port yields the following:

```
Calls/s: 0.9
MB/s: 0.9
Elements/s: 460,000
Average Queue depth: 0%
Time: 0
```

Which port did you monitor? These values are reasonable considering the sample rate chosen is 250 kHz and each sample is composed of two `short int` *Elements*.

I suggest you simplify your waveform as I have done and see if the issues continue. Make sure you are starting the waveform after it's been launched. Monitor the USRP_UHD's `dataShort_out` port and compare the results with what I've posted above. If the values are similar, the issue you're having is likely a result of one of the components you've removed.

Some additional information about your environment may also help identify the problem. What versions are you using (OS, Redhawk, FrontendInterfaces, USRP_UHD, etc.). What model of USRP are you using?